# Display html from json

Tags: html, node.js, json, express, ejs

I am writting a simple system displaying data from my JSON instead of using a database. Everything works fine except for the html tags, which are displayed as plain text. Also note that I am the only one able to write in the json file, that's why I want to display html tag from it.

So here is the output

From page : `<p>Test <b>Big Test</b> <i>Italic Test</i>.</p>`

From source : `&lt;p&gt;Test &lt;b&gt;Big Test&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;Italic Test&lt;/i&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;`

Here is the output I want : Test **Big Test** *Italic Test*.

Here is pretty much how I store it in my Json file :

```
{
  "table": [
    {
      "desc": "<p>Test <b>Big Test</b> <i>Italic Test</i>.</p>"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried many things from the internet without a lot of many success. I am using express.

Here is how I parse it (note that there are many fields in the table and I am iterating through them all)

`<%= parser['table'][i].desc %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using EJS as your template engine? If so then https://ejs.co/#docs offers the solution:

> <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
>
> <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template

So you want to use this

```
<%- parser['table'][i].desc %>
```

to avoid escaping of HTML/XML.

Comment: This is exactly this, I just started using EJS and was unaware of this and tried much more complex things in vain! Thank you very much sir, +1!

Comment: glad it worked; please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.